# Eclipse on OS X El Capitan Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I recently updated my MacBook Pro to El Capitan and now none of my Java code runs in Eclipse.

Every time I try to run any program I get the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class sim.app.geo.MK_3.MK_3WithUI

I have Googled and followed the guidance on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003352/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334625/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235827/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) including:

- [cleaning and rebuilding the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21170816/2560171)
- [checking Run Configurations have the correct Project and Main class details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26004181/2560171)
- [removing all old run configurations and trying again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536609/2560171)
- [adding the bin directory for the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355989/2560171)
- [checked all jar files are available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18726729/2560171)
- [reordering build class entries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18784020/2560171)

None of the above has helped.

I'm pretty sure my Java Build Path details are in order:

[image]
[image][image][image]

Details:

- Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
- Mac OS X El Capitan v. 10.11.4
- Java jdk1.8.0_45.jdk:  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk
- .jar files saved in /Library/Java/Extensions/ and /Library/Java/Test Backup/
- Eclipse Workspace: /Volumes/JetDrive/Drive/workspace/EngDModelOne

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed this problem and if anyone else has the same problem, here's what I did.

- I removed all the references to my old JAR files from my Project libraries
- I cleaned all my projects and rebuilt them. I then restarted Eclipse.
- I downloaded all the new versions of my JAR files from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/CatalogJar.htm) and replaced the old ones in my Java Library folders.
- I updated all my Project Libraries with the new JAR files and referenced the new Java JDK/JMF etc
- I cleaned all my projects and rebuilt them. I then restarted Eclipse.

Huzzah! Everything now works! From 3000+ errors to none and working projects.