# Java TextToSpeech Could not find or load main class model.Main

Tags: java, eclipse, class, jar, text-to-speech

I'm new with Java

I'm trying to use `TextToSpeech`, I have [Referenced libraries](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Text-To-Speech-Tutorial/tree/master/Mary%20TTS%20Program/libraries) and this [.java code](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Text-To-Speech-Tutorial/tree/master/Mary%20TTS%20Program/src/application) by particular example.

My `Main.java`:

```
package model;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech();
       tts.speak("Hello world", 1.0f, false, false);
   }
}
```

but when I'm trying to run, I got

> Error: Could not find or load main class model.Main

Project files:

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to run?

Comment: @Vishwaksena Hello, with Run button in Eclipse IDE

Comment: Did you try to right click on the Main class and select the Run option from there?

Comment: @Vishwaksena  I've clicked to `Main.java` as well as to `model`, but can't find Run option thare. Can you provide any guide, how to do that, please. I guess it not the `Build Path`, not sure

Comment: This is a most familiar issue and try to use the troubleshooting steps over here [eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003352/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Comment: @Vishwaksena well parameters was already added, I've edited question with image, but I got same error with run

Comment: What is in the _Problems_ view (the project folder is decorated with a red exclamation mark which means the project cannot be built; you have to fix this first)?

Comment: @howlger Hello, seems like yes, but I can't figure out what the reason of this. Is there any option to find reason of failure?

Comment: All errors and warnings are shown in the [_Problems_ view](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cprbview.htm). Copy the error message and added it to your question, please.

Comment: @howlger I've added error message to question, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three **source files** (`AudioPlayer.java`, `Main.java` and `TextToSpeech.java`) are **added by mistake as JARs to the build path** (source code are included via source folders instead). This prevents Eclipse from compiling the code and therefore the compiled Java class `model.Main` is missing.

To fix the problem do the following:

1. In ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***, in the tab ***Libraries* select** the following items:

   - ***AudioPlayer.java - TTS/src/model***
   - ***TextToSpeech.java - TTS/src/model***
   - ***Main.java - TTS/src/model***
2. Click ***Remove***
3. Click ***Apply and Close***

Comment: I've edited question, after removing, I got `exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The declared package "application" does not match the expected package "model" `

Comment: `AudioPlayer.java` and `TextToSpeech.java` are located in the package `model` but contain the line `package application;`. Either change `package application;` to `package model;` in both files or create a package `application` and move the two files to this package.