# Can not load main class

Tags: eclipse

I just installed Eclipse and began to work on a simple hello world program, but arrived on an error,

> "Error: Could not find or load main class Schedule."

I have tried everything in this thread [Eclipse error "Could not find or load main class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003352/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)
including editing path, changing the run configuration, cleaning, and many other solutions.

```
public class Schedule 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
```

I expected it to load hello world on console, but it does not show up, I have tried multiple solutions on many websites, but none of them seem to work.

**Edit**: here is a screenshot of my files
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJOvl.jpg

Comment: Try Rebuilding your project and check all library files are there in your project classpath

Comment: Did you store it in a Java project in the source folder as `Schedule.java`? Could you please show a screenshot?